# Github Pages : Display images from another branch for a private repository

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I have a private repository on github and using github pages. I have inserted an image to the markdown page using

```
!![Results](https://github.com/fireballpoint1/summerResearch/blob/parameter-input/simulation/argon/python_scripts/mayank/images/TestingPredictionVsOriginal-6-2.png)
```

The url points to **an image in the same repo on another branch**. (I am using 
 branch `gh-pages` for my page). Hence after rendering, the page doesn't show any image.
[image]

The markdown file on github is able to display the same image though:

[image]
While the github pages for a private repo is publically accessible, is there a way to make images availbale like this as well ?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't see the file because of the repo being private? Maybe it's because the picture doesn't have a proper path or something else...

Comment: What exactly are you using for your `url-to-image`? If you're pointing at the github page rather than the raw image link then you're pointing at the wrong thing. Update your question to show the actual URL...

Comment: @larsks I don't think it's the wrong link since Github's markdown renderer is able to show the same image. I have updated the question with the same

Comment: I get a 404 error if I try to follow the link in your question. Is that a private repository? If so, you're not going to be able to link to content in it.

Comment: @larsks yes. I have already mentioned it in the question

Comment: @mnestorov is there a way of checking the same? Right now the markdown render for the same file on Github is able to follow the link and show the picture, which I think is test enough for the link is right. But, it might be that it's not an image link for the HTML renderer

Comment: Yes the link seems correct :) . Now, I am not sure if you have the rights to access data from a public webpage to a private repo (hence the situation you fear to be in and the topic of your question). Correct me if I am wrong, but if I cannot follow the link and see the picture, why would any public webpage or GH page would be able too as well? Maybe a workaround is to add these picture(s) ande resources to your `gh-pages` branch and open them from that. Since you either way want to show them publicly, I gess it's not an issue to add them to that branch.

Comment: @mnestorov yes that can be done but that would require a lot of data replication and I am looking for a workaround to that. Also, it is interesting that the markdown render on github is able to show the image even though it is also using the exact same link. This is the thing that gives me hope to the feature

Comment: @fireball.1 that's interesting. I guess that your webpage is using the same markdown to generate the view, yet the pic is not showing up.

Comment: @fireball.1 okay is there a good reason as why these documentation pictures (at least I think they look like documentation pics) have to be in another branch? Can't all of them live in the `gh-pages` branch and then you can use them from there. Another solution that comes to mind is to still have `gh-pages` but through one of the other two methods, i.e. through your `master` branch and `docs` folder, where hopefully you will solve the problem. Also can you try to move one picture into the gh-pages branch and see if the pic will appear in the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Use the relative url instead of the full url. Then the engine will use the same reasoning for the file as the html file that was loaded.

So it would be:

`![Results](/parameter-input/simulation/argon/python_scripts/mayank/images/TestingPredictionVsOriginal-6-2.png)`

Instead of:

`![Results](https://github.com/fireballpoint1/summerResearch/blob/parameter-input/simulation/argon/python_scripts/mayank/images/TestingPredictionVsOriginal-6-2.png)`